# linux setgid() permission error

Tags: linux

So a user has a primary group and may belong to other supplementary group.

suppose user A primary group is G and supplementary groups G+1,G+2

User A runs a program is it possible to change group id to G+1

by default i know the group id will be set to G but an error is thrown when i run below program .erroris: Operation not permitted,where 4 is supplemental group a user belongs too.

According to the Manual ERRORS
EPERM  The calling process is not privileged (does not have the CAP_SETGID capability), and gid does not match the real group ID or  saved  set-group-ID  ofthe calling process.

How to list capability of a process ?

what does the saved set-group-id means ?

```
int
main ()
{
  int x = 0;
  char *error = "erroris";
  x = setgid (4);

  printf ("%d", x);
  perror (error);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many questions in one question!

Problem 1: cannot use `setgid` to change to a different goup id

Reasons for failure: User is not root, User is not euid `0`, User does not have `CAP_SETGID`

Problem 2: How do I list the capabilities of a process

Answer 2: Use [cap_get_proc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_get_proc) and [cap_to_text](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_to_text) to list the capabilities of a process

Problem 3: What does the saved set-group-id mean

Answer 3: When you use one of the `sete*id()` calls successfully, it records the old one in the saved id. This allows you to revert back to the saved value because this is one of the ids you're permitted to change to using the set call.